# Asp validation for exponential notation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a partial view, which binds object's properties to inputs. Most of the properties are floats and some of them are stored in exponential notation (1.23E+04), but when validation starts, those inputs, which are bound to exponential notation throw validation errors.

Here's an example of how my partial view looks like:

```
@model Namespace.Class

<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Property">property</label>
    <input asp-for="Property" class="form-control">
    <span asp-validation-for="property"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

And object:

```
public class Class
{
    public float Property { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to force validator to accept exponential notation?